# Angular 1.x: How to execute various action when checkbox is checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a HTML input checkbox field like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-change="itemChecked()"> Happy
```

My Angular 1.x code is like this:

```
$scope.itemChecked = function(){  
    // do something if checked
    // Eg: I have a google map and when this function is called, 
    //     it loads marker and adds businesses name.        


    // return to original state when unchecked 
    // Eg: When checked, it loads business in Google Map, 
    //     but when unchecked, its supposed to remove marker 
    //     points from google maps, as if the page loaded

};
```

I am able to:

> // do something if checked

but I am not able to revert back to original state.

How do I do that?

FYI: There is going to be multiple checkbox, so refreshing the page wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter inside the function and write the logic accordingly,

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-change="itemChecked(whatevervariable)">
```

In controller

```
$scope.itemChecked = function(variable){  
   if(variable)
   {
    //do this logic
   }
   else
   {
    //revert the logic
   }

};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nptab14w/)**

Comment: How to pass variable when checkbox is checked? This is not input field but a input type is checkbox. How can I pass "checked" when the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: I do not want to create my own directive. if/else condition works best for my project because there are other dependencies.

Comment: @asax there is no directive

Answer (score 0):

add ng-model to your input and check its value in your on change function

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"  ng-change="itemChecked()">

$scope.itemChecked = function(){  
     if($scope.checked == true){
        // do something if checked
     }
     else{
       // return to original state
     }

};
```